# Knights shortest path test case failing in foobar

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm having trouble with a google foobar question. I'm only failing one test case. I am suppose to determine the minimum number of moves a knight can make when moving between to points on a test board. the algorithm is shown below

```
import java.lang.Math;

public class Answer {   
    public static int answer(int start, int end) {

    int[][] board = new int[8][8];
    int[] startLocation = new int[2];
    int[] endLocation = new int[2];


    //chess board generated in nested loop
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        int[] row = new int[8];
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            row[i] = i + 8 * j;
        }
        board[j] = row;
    }

    //find locations of start and end points on board
    for (int m = 0; m < 8; m++){
        for (int n = 0; n < 8; n++){
            if (board[m][n] == start) startLocation = new int[]{m,n};
            if (board[m][n] == end) endLocation = new int[]{m,n};
        }
    }

    int[] delta = new int[]{Math.abs(endLocation[0] - startLocation[0]),Math.abs(endLocation[1]-startLocation[1])};

    if (delta[0] < delta[1]){
        int temp = delta[0];
        delta[0] = delta[1];
        delta[1] = temp;
    }
    //generate double array of possible moves
    if (delta[0] == 2 & delta[1] == 1) return 1;
    if ((delta[0]+ delta[1] == 2) || (delta[0] == 3 && delta[1] == 1) || 
            (delta[0] == 3 && delta[1] == 3) || (delta[0] == 4 && delta[1] == 2) || (delta[0] == 4 && delta[1] == 0)){
        return 2;
    }
    if ((delta[0] == 1 && delta[1] == 0) || (delta[0] == 3 && delta[1] == 0) || 
            (delta[0] == 5 && delta[1] == 0) || (delta[0] == 3 && delta[1] == 2) || (delta[0] == 4 && delta[1] == 3)
            || (delta[0] == 4 && delta[1] == 1) || (delta[0] == 6 && delta[1] == 1) || (delta[0] == 6 && delta[1] == 3)
            || (delta[0] == 5 && delta[1] == 2) || (delta[0] == 5 && delta[1] == 4)){
        return 3;
    }
    if ((delta[0] == 6 && delta[1] == 0) || (delta[0] == 2 && delta[1] == 2) ||
            (delta[0] == 5 && delta[1] == 1) || (delta[0] == 7 && delta[1] == 1) || (delta[0] == 6 && delta[1] == 2)
            || (delta[0] == 7 && delta[1] == 5) || (delta[0] == 7 && delta[1] == 3) || (delta[0] == 5 && delta[1] == 3)
            || (delta[0] == 4 && delta[1] == 4) || (delta[0] == 5 && delta[1] == 5) || (delta[0] == 6 && delta[1] == 6)
            || (delta[0] == 6 && delta[1] == 4)){
        return 4;
    }
    if ((delta[0] == 7 && (delta[1] == 0 || delta[1] == 2 || delta[1] == 4 || delta[1] == 6)) || (delta[0] == 6 && delta[1] == 5)){
        return 5;
    }
    return 6;
}
}
```

Under what circumstances can this code fail?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a debugging service. You should come up with some test cases yourself. You might even write a test program which generates all 64*64 possible inputs. Look at the ones that you would have the most difficulty solving by hand...and then solve them by hand to see if they match the output of your algorithm.

Comment: Note that you can significantly reduce the number of possible inputs if you take into account all of the symmetries of the chess board. For example, moving from the top left corner to the top right corner is a mirror image of moving from the bottom left corner to the bottom right corner. So the number of moves needed in both cases will be the exact same. In fact, you can use this in testing to be sure that you get the same answer for both cases. If you do not, then you know there is a problem with your code. Unfortunately if you do get the same answer, then it does not tell you much.

Comment: You basically precomputed all possible cases. Likely you made a mistake in one of them.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, the for the comments. I have already taken into account symmetry and solved a couple pairs by hand...I'll just try solving more...

Comment: I suggest that instead of coding the solutions as a bunch of if statements, that you develop an algorithm to count the number of moves needed. Solving problems with an algorithm is one of the most important skills of a computer programmer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The test case I didn't take into account was when the start in end position are one and the same. That's the one piece of the solution that was missing...

Answer (score 3):

If start is `0,0` and end is `1,1`, your answer is `2` moves, but that would require landing outside the chess board. Same for the other three corners, of course.

---

**UPDATE**

For the fun of it, I decided to write code to find the shortest path (one of them, anyway), and print the path taken.

*Code*

```
class Path {
    private final int  x;
    private final int  y;
    private final int  moveNo;
    private final Path prev;
    private Path(int x, int y, int moveNo, Path prev) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.moveNo = moveNo;
        this.prev = prev;
    }
    public static Path startAt(int x, int y) {
        if (x < 0 || x >= 8 || y < 0 || y >= 8)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid position: " + x + "," + y);
        return new Path(x, y, 0, null);
    }
    public Path move(Move move) {
        int newX = this.x + move.getX();
        int newY = this.y + move.getY();
        if (newX < 0 || newX >= 8 || newY < 0 || newY >= 8)
            return null; // Outside board
        for (Path step = this.prev; step != null; step = step.prev)
            if (step.x == newX && step.y == newY)
                return null; // Backstep
        return new Path(newX, newY, this.moveNo + 1, this);
    }
    public int getX() {
        return this.x;
    }
    public int getY() {
        return this.y;
    }
    public int getNumberOfMoves() {
        return this.moveNo;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if (this.prev == null)
            return this.x + "," + this.y;
        return this.prev + " -> " + this.x + "," + this.y;
    }
    public void printBoard() {
        char[][] board = new char[8][15];
        for (char[] row : board)
            Arrays.fill(row, ' ');
        for (Path step = this; step != null; step = step.prev)
            board[step.y][step.x * 2] = Character.forDigit(step.moveNo, 36);
        System.out.println("  +---------------+");
        for (char[] row : board)
            System.out.println("  |" + new String(row) + "|");
        System.out.println("  +---------------+");
    }
}

class Move {
    private static final Move[] KNIGHT_MOVES = {
            new Move(-1, -2), new Move( 1, -2),
            new Move( 2, -1), new Move( 2,  1),
            new Move( 1,  2), new Move(-1,  2),
            new Move(-2,  1), new Move(-2, -1) };
    private final int  x;
    private final int  y;
    public Move(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    public int getX() {
        return this.x;
    }
    public int getY() {
        return this.y;
    }
    public static Path find(int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY) {
        final Comparator<Path> distanceComparator = new Comparator<Path>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Path step1, Path step2) {
                int dx1 = step1.getX() - endX, dy1 = step1.getY() - endY;
                int dx2 = step2.getX() - endX, dy2 = step2.getY() - endY;
                return Integer.compare(dx1 * dx1 + dy1 * dy1, dx2 * dx2 + dy2 * dy2);
            }
        };
        Queue<Path> queue = new ArrayDeque<>();
        queue.add(Path.startAt(startX, startY));
        for (Path step; (step = queue.poll()) != null; ) {
            List<Path> nextSteps = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Move move : KNIGHT_MOVES) {
                Path newStep = step.move(move);
                if (newStep != null) {
                    if (newStep.getX() == endX && newStep.getY() == endY)
                        return newStep;
                    nextSteps.add(newStep);
                }
            }
            Collections.sort(nextSteps, distanceComparator);
            queue.addAll(nextSteps);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

*Test*

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    test(2,2, 3,3);
    test(0,0, 1,1);
    test(0,0, 7,7);
    test(0,0, 6,7);
    test(7,7, 0,0);
}
private static void test(int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY) {
    Path step = Move.find(startX, startY, endX, endY);
    System.out.println(step.getNumberOfMoves() + ": " + step.toString());
    step.printBoard();
}
```

*Output*

```
2: 2,2 -> 4,1 -> 3,3
  +---------------+
  |               |
  |        1      |
  |    0          |
  |      2        |
  |               |
  |               |
  |               |
  |               |
  +---------------+
```

```
4: 0,0 -> 2,1 -> 0,2 -> 2,3 -> 1,1
  +---------------+
  |0              |
  |  4 1          |
  |2              |
  |    3          |
  |               |
  |               |
  |               |
  |               |
  +---------------+
```

```
6: 0,0 -> 2,1 -> 3,3 -> 5,4 -> 7,5 -> 5,6 -> 7,7
  +---------------+
  |0              |
  |    1          |
  |               |
  |      2        |
  |          3    |
  |              4|
  |          5    |
  |              6|
  +---------------+
```

```
5: 0,0 -> 1,2 -> 3,3 -> 5,4 -> 7,5 -> 6,7
  +---------------+
  |0              |
  |               |
  |  1            |
  |      2        |
  |          3    |
  |              4|
  |               |
  |            5  |
  +---------------+
```

```
6: 7,7 -> 6,5 -> 4,4 -> 3,2 -> 2,0 -> 1,2 -> 0,0
  +---------------+
  |6   4          |
  |               |
  |  5   3        |
  |               |
  |        2      |
  |            1  |
  |               |
  |              0|
  +---------------+
```

Comment: the code is based off relative positioning. The start point will always be (for all intents and purposes) at (0,0). The distance from the second point will always be in positive units (x > 0, y > 0).

Comment: No, the starting point is given by the parameter `start`, and the ending point is given by the parameter `end`, both in the form of a number 0-63, mapping into a cell number. You should know this, since you coded it. If start is e.g. `2,2` and end is `3,3`, you can do it in two moves: `2,2` -> `4,1` -> `3,3`. However, if start is `0,0` and end is `1,1`, you can't move to `2,-1` or `-1,2` as the intermediate step. Which means you have to move `0,0` -> `2,1` -> `1,3` -> `3,2` -> `1,1`, i.e. 4 moves, even though the `delta` is the same (`1,1`). The flaw is that you ignore the board size.

Comment: Not just the board size, but the constraints of the physical board.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Guess that's what I meant. Thanks for clarifying. :-)